# Select Multiple Invoice No in single MysQl statement

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to select multiple Invoiceno from my database table with one mysql query but i get an empty records 
here what i've tried

```
$invoiceNo1="'".implode("','", $invoiceNo)."'";

$queryInv="SELECT invoice_no,invoice_date,invoicetype FROM invoice_lineitem where invoice_no in ($invoiceNo1)";
```

but i get an empty array

Comment: Can you print the request just after the two lines to see the complet Sql request

Comment: At the top, can you `print_r($invoiceNo`);` and display the results, and right below `$queryInv` can you echo it out, and edit your question with the two results. Are you getting any SQL error when running the query? Try and check to see if your result is false from the query, and display the `$mysqi->error`.

Comment: why are you using single and double quotes at the start and end of the implode function ?

Comment: @Mehar it is the right way to concatenate different values to be used in the IN clause in the query

Comment: echo $invoiceNo1 before using in the query to see if it is returning correct data

Comment: @Mayuris: have you tried running the query directly in the db? Do you get results? If the answer is yes you should check how the $invoiceNo array is populated. If no you are just getting the expected result based on the db contents.

Comment: thanks for reply i got it correct the problem was in my variable